# Custom Camera App crashes in some devices occasionally

Tags: android, crash, camera

I have made a custom Camera app which has a rectangle in Camera preview and on click it saves the Image inside the rectangle.

I have been able to make it works well on my Device which is Sony Xperia X8 running in android 2.3 and also on eclipse emulators 4.0.3, 4.1.2.

The problem is it crashes on Samsung galaxy S3 jelly bean (4.1).

The Camera is showing the preview but on click it crashes occasionally.

Some times it work perfect, other times it crashes.

Like i said, it works perfectly fine on some devices.

I don't have the phone with me so i cannot debug it.

Has it got anything to do with camera configuration?, i mean does samsung has a different camera config. that i don't know of?.

It seems mysterious that it is only crashing occasionally.

Comment: Having a log or stack trace would be helpful. Ask whoever has the device to email you a log right after the crash using a third party app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your application some time crash in **Galaxy S3** because of **OutOfMemoryException**. because that mobiles **Camera resolution** is **very high**.

Try to add this code with your code.

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback()
{

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opt;

        opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        Parameters parameters = arg1.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();

        int height11 = size.height;
        int width11 = size.width;
        float mb = (width11 * height11) / 1024000;

        if (mb > 4f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 4;
        else if (mb > 3f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 2;


        bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length,opt);

    }
}
```

Comment: what ever device you debug with device then you get OutOfMemoryException.... and that is the way to reduce image size....

Comment: you say in question in galaxy s3 it crashes...now you say i didn't get any error...exactly what you say?

Comment: you try above code or not ? ... and if you implement then also it not helpful for you then told me, that it is not working for you. and if you don't want this answer then also told me I removed it. ok.

Comment: then I give answer to @sachin but If you didn't get any error then why you reply to me... that solution for sachin because they have problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the camera issue you are having. But here is a lib, maybe it can help you to check the crash logs from different devices: **[Acra](https://code.google.com/p/acra/)**

Hope it helps:)